# Forçar navegardor a abrir o .pdf

Tags: php

Preciso abrir um arquivo .pdf direto no navegador. O problema é que este arquivo é gerado de um link externo e já vem com opção de download.

Estou tentado abrir desta forma:

```
<?php
$file = $_GET['arquivo']; // aqui to pegando o link por onde o arquivo é gerado
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$file.'"');
    readfile("{$file}");
  ?>
```

Mas da erro de leitura do pdf.

Segue o link do arquivo que preciso abrir:
https://boletoonline.caixa.gov.br/ecobranca/SIGCB/imprimir/0934772/14000000110730423

Apresenta os seguintes erros:

```
Warning: readfile(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in /home/suains55/public_html/webservicecaixa/view.php on line 8

Warning: readfile(): Failed to enable crypto in /home/suains55/public_html/webservicecaixa/view.php on line 8

Warning: readfile(https://boletoonline.caixa.gov.br/ecobranca/SIGCB/imprimir/0934772/14000000110730423): failed to open stream: operation failed in /home/suains55/public_html/webservicecaixa/view.php on line 8
```

Alguem pode ajudar?

Answer (score -2):

Amigo, tente essa forma:

```
header('Cache-Control: public');
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
$ativar_ssl=array(
    "ssl"=>array(
        "verify_peer"=>false,
        "verify_peer_name"=>false,
    ),
);

$resposta = base64_encode(file_get_contents("https://boletoonline.caixa.gov.br/ecobranca/SIGCB/imprimir/0934772/14000000110730423", false, stream_context_create($ativar_ssl)));

echo base64_decode($resposta);
```